# Getting error message while starting Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

'Starting Tomcat v6.0 server at localhost' has encountered a problem
Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost failed to start

Hi all,

When I am trying to start the Tomcat server from Eclipse, I am getting the following error in the pop up:

**'Starting Tomcat v6.0 server at localhost' has encountered a problem
Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost failed to start**

This error started coming all of a sudden.

Can anyone suggest what to do?

I had already deleted the Tomcat server and the instance, deleted some of the temporary files from the .metadata. Still no luck.

Comment: You should have looked at the output in the Console View, or the server instance logs on disk, for actual details.

Comment: I second looking at the console output. One likely cause is that another program is serving on the port Tomcat wants to use. This would explain why it happens suddenly - it might be you (or a service) started a program that uses the same port. If Tomcat uses port 80, there are many programs (ab)using the default HTTP port, such as Skype, for instance.

Comment: Is an another Tomcat running? Is any application using port `8080`?